# no "portlet producer application" in JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

I downloaded JDeveloper 11g to do some WSRP portlet development (who knew it was so "big"). However All the turorials I refernce talk about "portlet producer application" wizard which I dont have in my JDeveloper.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the WebCenter extensions to get the Portlet wizards.
Also make sure you are using JDeveloper 11.1.1.* and not 11.1.2.*
Use help->check for update to get the extension.

Comment: Thanks...what a roundabout way getting something so simple! Wonder if I would have been faster using IBM toolsets?

Comment: Actually with the IBM tools you would have needed to download multiple tools to get Java, SOA, DB and Portal capabilities - at least with JDeveloper (if you get the right version) you get a single IDE that integrates all of them. :-)